# Check whether there is a text at certain location on Matlab figure

Tags: matlab, figure

Is there any possibility to check whether there is a text at certain location on Matlab figure before print some text on that location?

I mean, some times if we have many curves and if we add some notes they might overlap at certain places. So I want to adjust note display location according to distance between previous text.

Comment: By "text" what do you mean? Please provide the code you're using to add text to your figures so we can see what functions you're using. Are you only referring to text that your own code has placed or do you also mean text from plot functions (e.g., axis labels, etc.)? It's probably possible to do something like this, but it would take some work as Matlab it's always the best at typography. A [grid system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grid_(graphic_design)) might be the way to go and look better as well.

Comment: By text I am referring a text object, such as, text(num(LasNanIndex,1),num(LasNanIndex,Inin(i)),[txt{1,Inin(i)}],'color', PlotColor,'FontSize',10);.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [findobj](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findobj.html) to look for text objects, and the get the position as you would for any property of a graphics object.

Example:

```
clear
clc

%// Create/plot data
x = -10:10;
y1 = x.^2;
y2 = 2*x-10;

plot(x,y1,'--r',x,y2,'-*k')

%// Add some text
t1 = text(-6,10,'Curve 1');
t2 = text(6,-4,'Curve 2');
```

The figure looks like this:

[image]

```
%// Find text objects. Of course normally you would not know beforehand
%their position

hText = findobj('Type','Text');

%// Get their position
Text1Pos = get(hText(1),'Position')
Text2Pos = get(hText(2),'Position')
```

Theses variables look like this:

```
Text1Pos =

     6    -4     0


Text2Pos =

    -6    10     0
```

So that would be quite easy to verify that no text objects is present at a given position.

Is this what you meant?

Comment: This is a start, but to be robust you need to check that the bounding boxes of the two text objects don't intersect unless you know a priori some maximal dimensions (something like a grid scheme). You may be able to do this with the `'Extent'` property.

Comment: yep agreed @horchler. I'll edit my answer to refine it thanks